# Probability using Venn

Tags: probability

For two events A and B we have Pr[A′] =.71, Pr[B] =.43, and Pr[A∪B] =.65. Find Pr[A∩B].

I'm wondering how to start solving this one. Should I try and find the universal set? Unsure about the first step. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) = P(A \cup B)$

and $P(A) = 1 - P'(A)$.

That should be enough to finish the problem off.